# Visual Studio: local bookmarks / in-code shortcuts to another part of the code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I know that Visual Studio has global Bookmarks to create shortcuts to commonly used code, but sometimes I would like to have "local" bookmarks - like links in code comments - that would navigate IDE to a specific file and line.

Example: when I update a class that is a data structure (for example add a new property), I need to navigate to 5 different places in my code where this class is used to add handling for it. "References" (above class definition) often give too many results that have no easy way of being filtered to my intent, so I'd rather create such links manually.

Is it possible to create bookmarks/links to other parts of the code that would be visible only when editing a particular class?

Comment: No, that isn’t possible

Comment: [The Task List window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-the-task-list?view=vs-2022) can meet your requirements to a certain extent. In the Task List you can add custom comments, you can add comments with specific keywords that represent bookmarks. In the Task List window, you will see a list of tasks extracted from the code comments.